# Render the first few items of a queryset, and then load more items via ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I want to render the first 5 comments of a `Comment` queryset. But then I want to be able to load the next 20 comments when a user clicks a button.

**views**

```
def article(request, category, id):

    name = resolve(request.path).kwargs['category']
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id, entered_category=name)

    #comments
    current_page = int(request.GET.get('page_val', '1'))
    page_size = 5
    limit = page_size * current_page
    offset = limit - page_size

    new_comments_list = Comment.objects.filter(destination=id, parent_id=0).order_by('-timestamp')[offset:limit]

    counts = new_comments_list.count()
    total_pages = counts / page_size
    if counts % page_size != 0:
        total_pages += 1
    is_last = True if current_page >= total_pages else False

    comment_list = Comment.objects.filter(parent_id=0, post=post).order_by('-score__upvotes')[:2]

    context = {
        'id': id,
        'comment_list': new_comments_list,
        'is_last': is_last,
        'instance': instance,
    }
    if request.is_ajax():
        if new_comments_list:
            return render(request, 'list_ajax.html', context)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('last')

    return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

**comments_base.html**

```
<div class="commentsContainer">

    {% include 'comments.html' %}
    #I can append the new comments here
    <p class="more_comments">more comments</p>
</div>
```

**comments.html**

```
{% block comments %}

    {% for i in comment_list %}
        {% if i.parent_comment %}
            <div class="comment_shell hasParent">
         {% else %}
            <div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class='comment_div' data-comment_id="{{ i.id }}">
            <div class="left_comment_div">
                <div class="username_and_votes">
                    <h3><a class='username_foreign'>{{ i.user }}</a></h3>
                    {% for j in i.score.all %}
                        <span class="upvotes">{{ j.upvotes }}</span>
                        <span class="downvotes">{{ j.downvotes }}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <br>
                <p>{{ i.comment_text }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% include 'comments.html' with comment_list=i.replies.all %}
    </div>

    {% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

So as you can see in my views I only get the first 5 comments. So by doing this, is there any viable way to load the next 20 items of the queryset (via AJAX)? Or alternatively, should I initially load the whole queryset, but only show the first 5 (hide the rest through jquery)? And then load the next 20 comments through jquery? Or is that not viable? Appreciate recommendations.

Edited: I've added full code.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/

Comment: That doesn't appear to be AJAX? I don't want page reload when loading more comments

Comment: You can use that module for slicing querysets

Comment: you can have a look into Django Endless Pagination package

Comment: @itzMEonTV Does it say how to load the next items of the queryset after slicing? Can't seem to find it.

Comment: Yes. It can accept `page` and `count_per_page` (not sure).But it is easy to give custom parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the custom pagination logic to achieve your goal.First do a pagination logic and create the offsets and limits regarding page values.Function of this logic is to use same function for appending data via ajax using django's inbuilt method **request.is_ajax()**

```
def yourview(request):
    current_page = int(request.GET.get('page_val', '1'))
    page_size = settings.PAGE_SIZE_WEB (replace with your number e.g 5)
    limit = page_size * current_page
    offset = limit - page_size

    new_comments_list = Comment.objects.all()[offset:limit] #your query will return data accrodign page size and page no
    counts = Comment.objects.all().count()

    total_pages = counts / page_size
    if counts % page_size != 0:
        total_pages += 1
    is_last = True if current_page >= total_pages else False
    context = { 
           "new_comments_list":new_comments_list,
           "is_last":is_last  
      }

    if request.is_ajax():
        if new_comments_list:
            return render(request, 'comments.html', context)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('last')
    return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

In the template define your div in which you can append your comments
**article.html**

```
<div class="comment-div">
  {% include 'comments.html' with is_last=is_last comment_list = comment_list %}  <!-- first time it will be loaded with page no 1 and when you call jquery it will be loaded with respective page number. -->
</div>
 <input type="hidden" id="page_val" value="2" /> <!-- setting page no according jquery calls ( by default it will be 2 for getting next comment data ) -->
```

your **comments.html** file,

```
{% for i in comment_list %}
    {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Do the jquery logic to append the data,
**yourfilename.js**

```
$(body).on('click','#append_data',function(){
      var page_val = $('#page_val').val();
      $.ajax({
        url: "/yoururl",
        type: "GET",
        data: {"page_val":page_val},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != "last") {
                page_val++;
                $('#page_val').val(page_val); #need to increment page no to get incremented number to get next page data
                #append your data on comment-div
            }
            else if (data == "last" ) {
                #hide show more comments
             }
        })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added the full code in my edit, if you could have a look thad be great. I'm having trouble understanding your code, especially the template usage. So basically, I have 3 templates in usage currently. `article.html` is the parent template, which is the one I initially load in the `article()` view. `comments_base.html` is a child template, and then `comments.html` is the child of `comments_base`. So when you say "In the template define your div in which you can append your comments"; would that be my `comments_base`? That's where I can append the new comments.

Comment: You passing comments as context in article view ?

Comment: Yes I have to, as the attributes of the comments are based on the article.

Comment: Ok, what i suggest is on page load pass the article and comments ( first 20 ) in same template. Then,when you call ajax ( same view url ) just render the comments context with comments_ajax.html by using request.is_ajax() method. In ajax success you have to append those comment in your particular div.

Comment: I saw you edited question. You are including 'comments.html' in ''comments.html'  which will create infinite loop.I suggest remove comments_base.html. Include comments.html directly in your article.html with passing comments context. After the ajax call render comments.html with new comments and append data on comments div on success callback.

Comment: I include `comments.html` in `comments.html` only for comment replies, not for the parent comments (which are the ones being appended). I do this to create endless replies (threaded comments). Is there any way I can adjust your code to keep `comments.base.html`? And append the new comments in `.commentsContainer` under `{% include 'comments.html' %}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146823/discussion-between-aniket-and-zorgan).

Answer (score 0):

You should create new view function what return comments for article and then i recommend to use [django-el-pagination](http://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) app what do all work for you.